# How to configure Microsoft Bot Framework with Office365 channel

Tags: office365, botframework

I build an MS Bot and published the bot to the Portal. Now i would enable and configure the email-channel with my outlook.com email address for my bot. I use the Office 365 Home Abbonement.

I get the failure "Unable to validate the given credentials" and i'm sure that my password is correct.

Have i do same configurations on my outlook account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use business office.